# Redshift ROW_ID column wrapping?

Tags: amazon-redshift

Redshift's `ROW_ID` column is somewhat similar to PostgreSQL's `OID` column.
That's a "unique" key for each record in a table, a hidden column added to each table.

Would you expect `ROW_ID` to be wrapped at some point?

In PostreSQL, `OID` column are 32 bits only -

> OIDs are implemented using 4-byte unsigned integers. They are not
> unique–OID counter will wrap around at 2³²-1. OID are also used to
> identify data types (see
> /usr/include/postgresql/server/catalog/pg_type_d.h).

Because of the wrapping, OIDs in PostgreSQL are not truly unique.

What's scale of `ROW_ID` in RedShift? Are they expected to be wrapped at some point? Can we expect `ROW_ID` to be unique? To be monotonically increasing?

Can't find documentation on this.

ps. `ROW_ID` is documented at least here https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/redshift/latest/dg/c_load_compression_hidden_cols.html but it might has been removed in later versions of Redshift? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an `int8`, so 64 bits.  You can examine it via `pg_attribute`.  The system tables indicate `raw` encoding, which I think I recall looked plausable for how that column was behaving (but the behaviour of the other two system columns (the MVCC columns) does not fit with `raw`, and I thought they used to be marked as `runlength`).

I've wondered if it's really used, since I believe in Postgres it was phased out, but Redshift is originally from Postgres 8, and I think at that point it was still in use.

As for monotonical increment, I've not looked, but I doubt it - you'd have to have some central point handing out numbers, which would be a serious bottleneck.  I might guess it acts like an `identity` column, where each slice independently generates numbers, so you end up with unique numbers, and always ascending, but not contiguous or monotonic.  If I remember correctly you cannot query the system columns using `SELECT` (unlike Postgres).  You have a limited ability to see their values using `minvalue` and `maxvalue` from `STV_BLOCKLIST`, as `int8` is used directly to compute its sortkey value, so if you write a single row into a table, you can see it's value, by examining its sortkey value.  So if you write one row, then a second row, then delete the first row, then vacuum, then assuming no row renumbering occurs (which actually it might well do - Postgres does, when it vacuums), then you'll see the value for the second row.  Remember to use a sortkey column, always with the same value, to keep all your rows on one slice, so the rows you're adding do in fact all end up in the same block.